# Is it correct to use 'could' to describe present ability?

Tags: usage, modal-verbs, could-modal, can-modal

The following conversation is taken from the movie, *[The Menu](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9764362/characters/nm0115402?ref_=tt_cl_c_16)* (2022)[spoiler alert]:

> **Peter**: I mean, really, you should have your own place. Right?
>
> **Lilian** (a food critic): And I could help you with that.
>
> **Katherine** (a sous-chef): I'm sure you could, Ms. Bloom.
>
> **Lilian**: I could. I could. We, we would just have to talk about the, the, you know, the... the dying thing.

Is it correct to use *could* instead of *can* to describe a present ability?

Comment: *I **can** do that* usually implies *...and I **will***, but *I **could** do that* usually implies *...but I **won't*** (or at least ***...might not***). In both cases, speaker has the *ability*.

Comment: I don't recall this dialogue in the movie, but unless Ms Bloom is something *more* than just "a customer" in the restaurant, it's not obvious why the chef would know her name, and believe Ms Bloom was really able to help her run her own restaurant. So I can't guess exactly what C is implying with *I'm sure you **could*** (apart from perhaps she thinks that although B *could* help her, in practice she probably *won't*).

Comment: The chef knows Ms Bloom's name because she is a regular customer, so he already knows her. This conversation starts at (01:03:36) in the movie.

Comment: What makes you think this is incorrect? **I could [do something]** is a very common way to express that one has the ability to do something, but with the added nuance that it might not actually happen, or that some agreement is required before it would be possible.  "Can" on the other hand,  just expresses "ability" without the same nuance.

Comment: From what I recall, things don't end well for the diners in *The Menu*, on account of the chef's dastardly plans (I forgot it was a male chef in earlier comment). So I assume his ***I'm sure you could** [do helpful things for me]* is sardonic / patronising *(Sure, maybe you **could** help me. But you won't get the chance)*.

Comment: Because almost all grammar books and references (even on the web) says that 'COULD' is used to talk about 'general ability' in the past. Only one book (which is, Collins COBUILD ENGLISH USAGE 4TH EDITION) says the following: (Could is also used to talk about ability in the present, but it has a special meaning . If you say that someone could do something, you mean that they have the ability to do it, but they don't in fact do it. Example: We could do much more in this country to educate people.)

Comment: [FumbleFingers] My question is why did she say (I could) in the first place, knowing that he was about to kill them. If 'could' means 'I can but I won't', then she should have said 'I can' to assure him that she will - even if she was deceiving him.

Comment: It seems to be a hypothetical here: if C had their own place (or at least started working towards that goal) then B could help. Merriam-Webster says [could](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/could) is used "as an alternative to can suggesting less force or certainty or as a polite form in the present"

Comment: @FumbleFingers the chef in the dialogue is a sous-chef, a woman called Katherine, not that it makes any real difference but I've seen the film and I remember the scene.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I remember someone escaped for no obvious reason, but that movie didn't exactly leave a lasting impression on me. On the other hand, I can practically remember *tasting* some  of the yummy street food in the movie *Chef (2014)* (perhaps I was chomping on something particularly tasty while I watched it! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a conditional "could".

Normal conditionals use "would":

> I would be able to help you find your own place.

You might want to use "can" instead of "be able".  But this is ungrammatical:

> *I would can help you.

The modal verb "can" is defective and you can't say "will can" or "would can".

Instead you should use "could"

> I could help you.

This "could" means the same as "would be able".

When conditionals are used without an "if" clause, the condition is implied an may be difficult to make explicit.  Here it is something like "I'm sure you could help me, (if I let you help me... but I won't let you help me)"

Answer (score 2):

The dialogue is similar to a bargaining exchange, by using "could", the food critic (Lillian) is telling the sous-chef (Katherine) that there is a possibility that she ***could*** get her own restaurant (apparently every sous-chef's dream) if Katherine allows them to escape. In this instance, *could* does not refer back to something that possibly or regularly happened in the past. In this exchange *could* refers clearly to the present

**I *could* help you with that** = There is a chance, a good one, that I will help make your dream come true
**I *can* help you with that**  = I am in a position to help you achieve your dream

> **8.** [MODAL VERB](https://https:/https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/could) B1+
> You use **could**, or *couldn't* in questions, **when you are making offers and suggestions.**
> • We need money right? We could go around and ask if people need odd jobs done or something.
> • You could look for a career abroad where environmental jobs are better paid and more secure.
> <sub>Collins Dictionary</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I still have a point I wish you could make it clear.
Does (I could)  have a positive connotation or a negative connotation. Example: if someone asked me: (Could you help me move to my new apartment this weekend?)
and I said (Yes, I could help you. I only have time on Saturday afternoon.)
Does this mean that I am really willing to help you (positive connotation), but I might not be able to or that I have to review my schedule first.
OR
that I'm not really willing to help (negative connotation) maybe because I really don't have time or I just don't want to help?

Comment: @J.a.deb   If I can help someone, I'd say: "Yes, no problem. What about Saturday?” or "Sure I can ,but I can only lend a hand on Saturday.” Replying "I could help you move home on Saturday” suggests that I am not certain I will be free time, maybe a need a day or two before I can commit myself.

Comment: Thank you. You know, many a time I find differences between what is written in grammar books and what is given on Youtube channels and the responses I get in forums. For example, I read (or watch on Youtube) that in a certain situation you should say or respond in this way; then when I post a question in a forum about the same issue, I get responses like: "Who told that?" or "We don't say it this way"....!!???